# (mysql(mariadb 10.x.x)) Where match against with fulltext and Order by primary key say 'using filesort'

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause

I'm DB developer 
when I tested my selecting query, result said that 'using where;using filesort'
I know that 'using where' is fine, but problem is 'using filesort'

Briefly, my table that is named 'QUESTION' has the structure like below.

**QUESTION_IDX(PK) | TITLE(FULLTEXT) | REG_DATE**

and my select query is like this below..

**SELECT QUESTION_IDX
    FROM 'QUESTION'
    WHERE MATCH(TITLE) AGAINST('*abc*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    ORDER BY QUESTION_IDX DESC
    LIMIT 0,18**

this query say that
 
TITLE -> 'Using where; Using filesort'

please inform me the solution removing filesort
Thanks

Comment: test is using 'EXPLAIN' query

Comment: 'Using filesort' isn't necessary bad. It doesn't always translate into an on disk activity as sorts can be done in memory. The `file` location is largely historical where sorts where always on disk.

Comment: Probably should of mentioned, its currently not possible to do a FT search and have an order by using a different index on table within a query..